# When writing a DateTime value using openxlsx, a "x" is written followed by DateTime value in the next row instead of just the DateTime value

Tags: r, datetime, openxlsx

I would like to write DateTime values to an excel sheet using openxlsx. When I try to do this, instead of just the DateTime value, I get a lowercase "x" on one row followed by the DateTime in the subsequent row.  This occurs whether I use write.xlsx or writeData.  I also tried converting the DateTime using as.POSIXlt or as.POSIXct, converting the date with timezone specified or not, and get the same result.

The UTC DateTime values are coming from a PerkinElmer microplate reader file.

Below is a code snippet that gives me this result.  Any advice or help is appreciated, Thanks!

```
library(openxlsx)
library(lubridate)

date <- as_datetime("2022-04-07T22:15:08+0000", tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
options(openxlsx.datetimeFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

write.xlsx(date,"test.xlsx",overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`write.xlsx`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.5/topics/write.xlsx) says in section Arguments that `x` is (my emphasis)

> A **data.frame** or a **(named) list** of objects that can be handled by `writeData()` or `writeDataTable()` to write to file.

So apparently an atomic vector is first coerced to data.frame and since the data argument name is `x`, so is its column header.

This also happens when writing a named list `date_list <- list(date = date)`. A workbook with a sheet named `date` is created and the data in it has a column header `x`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation!  It was fixed by passing colNames = FALSE to write.xlsx: `write.xlsx(date,"test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE, colNames = FALSE)`